# Why am I getting "Mismatched contact type." when I try to import any contacts?

Tags: contacts, import, data-import

Wordpress 6.1.1, Civi 5.59.4

I have been getting the error "Mismatched contact type." which is possibly linked to this: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3927 but that appears patched since 5.54

I cannot replicate in demo master.

However I noticed that the dedupe rule options do not change based on contact type selection, they all show up.

[image]

When I select the right dedupe rule - it imports without issue.

Comment: I've seen that dedupe dropdown problem before but can't remember where. Will see if I can find.

Comment: I found the site, but I never resolved it, I just updated the labels so it was clear which contact types they applied to. For the record that site is 5.57.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed by https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25515/files in 5.60.

```
--- a/CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php
+++ b/CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php
@@ -483,7 +483,7 @@ public static function buildSubTypes() {
   }
 
   public static function buildDedupeRules() {
-    $contactType = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('parentId', 'Positive');
+    $contactType = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('parentId', 'String');
     $dedupeRules = CRM_Dedupe_BAO_DedupeRuleGroup::getByType($contactType);
 
     CRM_Utils_JSON::output($dedupeRules);
```